# T_IF error in php registration form

Tags: php

I am trying to get an php registration form working, but i am having problems with an if/else statement. but can't quite figure it out.

```
ERROR: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in E:\xampp\htdocs\test\register.php on line 21
```

PHP Code :

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$repassword = $_POST['repassword'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

if ($username && $password && $repassword  && $email)
{
        if ($password == $repassword)
        {
            include ("connect.php");
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query)
            if($numrows == 0)         <<- LINE 21
            {
                echo "Username not taken";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "That username is taken!";
            }
        }
        else
            echo "Password did not match";  }
else
    echo "You did not fill in every field!";

else {//show registration form Stackoverflow cant display it properly.}
```

Maby one of you guys sees the problem.

Thanxs in advance,

Jim

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon `;` right after your query

```
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query); //here is missing wich is causing the error
```

**EDIT** as Kavi Siegel suggested it seems you are also missing a closing bracket in last else (the one you have is commented)

```
else 
{//show registration form Stackoverflow cant display it properly.


} //this was commented
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question but, but heads up, OP should also be aware that the closing to his `else{` at the bottom of the code block is commented out and that will error as well.

Comment: Thanxs that did the trick!

Comment: @user2022298 you welcome, don't forget to accept answer for help people in the future with similar problems

Answer (score 2):

Close your `If Conditions` properly.

```
if ($username && $password && $repassword  && $email)
{
        if ($password == $repassword)
        {
            include ("connect.php");
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query)
            if($numrows == 0)         <<- LINE 21
            {
                echo "Username not taken";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "That username is taken!";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Password did not match";  }
 } else
    echo "You did not fill in every field!";
```

Answer (score 0):

Put semicolon after this

```
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query)
```

change it to this

```
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
```